# NumberFormatexception for input string 999999999

Tags: java, parsing

this is my `html` code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
</div>
```

this is my `controller`

```
int phonenumber=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("phonenumber").trim());
```

I am gettting error of `NumberFormatException for input string  '9999999999'`

How to solve it.

Even though it is a number why cannot I parse it?

Answer (score 2):

`9999999999` is outside the valid range of values for the `int` data type (-2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, inclusive), as specified by the [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) constants.

You cannot represent a full phone number in an `int`, you would have to omit the prefix and area code (0000000 - 9999999).  Otherwise, use a `long` instead (-2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>-1, inclusive),  `Long.parseLong()` will happily handle `9999999999`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception` because you are trying to convert '9999999999' into an Integer, and the max range of type `int` is `2147483647`.

So try `Long.parseLong("9999999999")` instead if you are insisting on converting phone number from `String` into numbers. Storing and manipulating phone numbers as `int` or `long` will result in some inconsistencies in the future.

If you are doing that to check whether all the input characters are digits or not, you can use other ways such as using **Regular Expressions**. This way is very helpful since you can check formats, separator, etc. See this sample from [MKyoung](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-validate-phone-number-in-java-regular-expression/) site:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidatePhoneNumber {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

      String sPhoneNumber = "605-8889999";
      //String sPhoneNumber = "605-88899991";
      //String sPhoneNumber = "605-888999A";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{7}");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

      if (matcher.matches()) {
          System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");
      }
 }
}
```

And another simple way is to have a method which checks all the digits of a phone number are really digits:

```
public boolean isAllCharactersDigit(String phoneNumber){
    for(char c: phoneNumber.toCharArray()){
        if(!Character.isDigit(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The range of an `int` in Java is `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

`9,999,999,999` is out of range and that is what is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check parseInt() method in Oracles doc
[parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

It clearly says

**An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:**

> The first argument is null or is a string of length zero. The radix is
>   either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than
>   Character.MAX_RADIX.
>
> Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix,
>   except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or
>   plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than
>   length 1. The value represented by the string is not a value of type
>   int.

**Examples:**

```
 parseInt("0", 10) returns 0
 parseInt("473", 10) returns 473
 parseInt("+42", 10) returns 42
 parseInt("-0", 10) returns 0
 parseInt("-FF", 16) returns -255
 parseInt("1100110", 2) returns 102
 parseInt("2147483647", 10) returns 2147483647
 parseInt("-2147483648", 10) returns -2147483648
 parseInt("2147483648", 10) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseInt("99", 8) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseInt("Kona", 10) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseInt("Kona", 27) returns 411787
```